# How to set a variable value on receiving a message in telegram bot

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

When I hit the below endpoint, I am able to receive a message on the telegram bot.

`https://api.telegram.org/<token>/sendMessage`

However, I would like to process the incoming message and set a variable value, For example: when the bot receives a message with text as "onChatEnded", I would like to modify a Map variable.

I tried override the sendMessage method but that doesn't seem to work.